# Conditional Formating Question

Tags: list

I'm just having trouble with setting a formula on a list that I have to apply some conditional formatting. I have searched and am still trying to understand the formating and get different answer from different sites.

What I want to do is that I have a column lableled DateEntered and a column lalbel DateRequired, I need to see if the date required is within 10 days then I want to change the formating

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a calculated field that adds 10 days to your date.  See the formulas here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx

Then apply the conditional formatting to the calculated field rather than the original field you're using.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dash a Jquery to acheive this Check this [Link](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2009/04/sharepoint-calculated-column-and-jquery.html)

If you are using Sharepoint 2010 Try this [link](http://markviky.blogspot.in/2010/10/create-list-view-conditional-formatting.html)